# Find k smallest values of of a 2D array slice of a 3D Array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I've read through other questions where other people are trying to find the *k* smallest values with `np.partition` or [`np.argpartition`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642353/find-the-n-smallest-items-in-a-numpy-array-of-arrays). However, these seem like simple 1D or 2D arrays to operate on.

What I have is a 3D array where I'm taking a 2D slice of it and trying to find the 4 smallest values as such:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(556)

big_array = np.random.randint(0,200,size = (15,9,3))
for i in range(3):
    min_vals = np.sort(big_array[:,:,i].flatten())[:4]
    print("The smallest values for last axis #{} are: {:.1f},{:.1f},{:.1f},{:.1f}".format(i,*min_vals))
```

Unfortunately, it seems like `np.partition` doesn't like it when the kth argument is larger than the dimension of whatever axis you're trying to specify, probably because I don't fully comprehend the syntax. Likewise, it doesn't look like `np.sort` or `np.argsort` have options for multiple axes arguments.

Is there a way to accomplish this without using a for loop or list comprehension?

Comment: you are looking to get 4 smallest values for each 2d slice from a 3d array? is that the objective?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can sort the reshaped array along the first axis and extract the results from there. Your loop and flatten is the same as:

```py
big_array.reshape(-1, big_array.shape[-1])
```

So, your code would be:

```py
top_4_per_last_axis = np.sort(big_array.reshape(-1, big_array.shape[-1]), 0)[:4]
```

Result:

```py
array([[ 0,  2,  0],
       [ 1,  3,  2],
       [ 1,  6,  3],
       [ 2,  9, 12]])
```

Comment: So the -1 in ```reshape``` forces numpy to constrain the 2nd dimension (of the reshaped array) to be the same size as the last dimension of ```big_array```?

Comment: When using reshape, -1 can be used for one of the dimensions and tells numpy it should infer the shape based on the other dimensions it is given. You can see this mentioned in the [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) documentation under the `newshape` argument description.

Comment: So, in this example, I told numpy to use `big_array.shape[-1]` for the last dimension. Because the total number of elements must be constant, the first dimension must be `np.prod(big_array.shape)/big_array.shape[-1]`.

Comment: Never thought ```np.reshape``` would be the way to flatten my array that easily. Thanks for the help!